# How to bypass human verification 'press and hold' using Selenium in Python?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, iframe

I am trying to scrape some product reviews using Selenium and Python from this [site](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Bounce-Fresh-Linen-Scented-Fabric-Softener-Dryer-Sheets-240-Count/729676143?athcpid=729676143&athpgid=athenaItemPage&athcgid=null&athznid=PWVUB&athieid=v0&athstid=CS020&athguid=b27f7edc-007-17b02b06336f66&athancid=null&athena=true) but it connects another [site](https://www.walmart.com/blocked?url=L2lwL0Nsb3JveC1EaXNpbmZlY3RpbmctV2lwZXMtMjI1LUNvdW50LVZhbHVlLVBhY2stQ3Jpc3AtTGVtb24tYW5kLUZyZXNoLVNjZW50LTMtUGFjay03NS1Db3VudC1FYWNoLzE0ODk4MzY1&uuid=9ed7f800-f288-11eb-ad50-1b3c9c7d7310&vid=9cf07351-f288-11eb-9ab5-ef26d206453b&g=b) and shows a popup at any point randomly, where I need to press and hold the button for human verification.

I am using chrome web driver and tried to solve it, to get the path using `driver.find_element_by_xpath` and many other ways. I also found that the 'Press and Hold' button is inside an iframe and so tried to switch to the iframe by `driver.switch_to_frame('//iframe')` or `driver.switch_to_frame(0)` but I failed. I can't find any iframe name or id to take any action.

**Is there any way to bypass or take action (pressing and holding the button) whenever it occurs (as a site or popup) and also dismiss other popups during the process using selenium and python?**
any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @CodingOtaku No, its different

Comment: As you can see this is not similar to google captcha where you may need to select some car photos or click a checkbox to verify as a human, its totally different, here it requires to press and hold the item/button, where the button is inside an iframe, where the iframe doesn't have any id or name to identify. Its not at all similar as Google captcha, I hope you understand.

Comment: you can switch to the pop up using `browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[index_of_window])`.
If there is no obvious way to get the IFrame then find its [xpath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) to switch to it.
"a popup at any point randomly" it's annoying so you'll have to constantly check for its existence.

But as I said before, even if you bypass the CAPTCHA, they'll soon change it's behavior to break all crawlers.

Comment: Most of the time, it connects the website for verification where the position of the button is same. But I can't find its xpath or iframe id. Possibly there are some code related to JavaScript with this iframe. At least I need to locate it (as it is shown in the centre) and press and hold it. I can handle other popups, but mainly this one is creating the issue. Randomly means this verification site occurs randomly,  we can detect it by matching current url but how to find that button to press it! Idk!

Comment: From what I see, there are 10 Iframes under the `<div id="px-captcha">`. I believe they are simply selecting one frame randomly and hiding the rest. the one showing the CAPTCH has `display:block` in the inline styles. does that help?

Comment: I tried it but its not working for me while I am trying to find the element using the xpath or id. Is it working for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235515/discussion-between-coding-otaku-and-pranta-palit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jacob's solution from this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68848948/16258342) solves this problem.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = wd.Chrome('./web driver/chromedriver.exe')
target_url = 'https://www.walmart.com/blocked?url=L2lwL0Nsb3JveC1EaXNpbmZlY3RpbmctV2lwZXMtMjI1LUNvdW50LVZhbHVlLVBhY2stQ3Jpc3AtTGVtb24tYW5kLUZyZXNoLVNjZW50LTMtUGFjay03NS1Db3VudC1FYWNoLzE0ODk4MzY1&uuid=9ed7f800-f288-11eb-ad50-1b3c9c7d7310&vid=9cf07351-f288-11eb-9ab5-ef26d206453b&g=b'
driver.get(target_url)
driver.maximize_window()

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#px-captcha')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.click_and_hold(element)
action.perform()
time.sleep(10)
action.release(element)
action.perform()
time.sleep(0.2)
action.release(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Chromedriver Undetected..
Check out the git link for setup.
Quite simple to integrate
https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.example.com')
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for Walmart