# How to long press (Press and Hold) mouse left key using only Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe, mouseevent, captcha

I am trying to scrape some review data from the Walmart site using Selenium in Python, but it connects this [site](https://www.walmart.com/blocked?url=L2lwL0Nsb3JveC1EaXNpbmZlY3RpbmctV2lwZXMtMjI1LUNvdW50LVZhbHVlLVBhY2stQ3Jpc3AtTGVtb24tYW5kLUZyZXNoLVNjZW50LTMtUGFjay03NS1Db3VudC1FYWNoLzE0ODk4MzY1&uuid=9ed7f800-f288-11eb-ad50-1b3c9c7d7310&vid=9cf07351-f288-11eb-9ab5-ef26d206453b&g=b) for human verification. After inspecting this '**Press & Hold**' button, somehow when I find the element, it comes out as an [**object HTMLIFrameElement**], not as a web element. And the element appears randomly inside any of the iframes, among 10 iframes. It can be checked using a loop, but, ultimately we can't take any action in selenium without a web element.

Though this verification also occurs as a popup, I was trying to solve it for this page first. Somehow I located the position of this button using the `div` as a webelement.

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='px-captcha']")
frame_x = iframe.location['x']
frame_y = iframe.location['y']
actions.move_to_element(iframe).move_by_offset(frame_x-550, frame_y+70).build().perform()
```

if I perform a `context.click()` or right click, it is visible that mouse position is in the middle of the button.
[image]

Now, if I can perform **long press** or **Press & Hold** the left mouse button for a while, I guess this verification can be cleared. For this I tried to take action using `click()` and `click_and_hold` and also with the `key_down` methods (as pressing ctrl and enter does the same as long press) in `action`, but no response as these methods release the buttons, can't be long pressed. I tried

```
actions.move_to_element(iframe).move_by_offset(frame_x-550,frame_y+70).click_and_hold().pause(20).perform()
actions.move_to_element(iframe).move_by_offset(frame_x-550, frame_y+70).actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).actions.key_down(Keys.ENTER).pause(20).perform()
```

.....and so many ways! **How can I solve it using Selenium**?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @loganhuskins I didn't find any way to press such verification using selenium. Just for completing the task, I used `PyAutoGui` to solve this issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's my make-shift solution.  The key is the release after 10 seconds and click again.  This is how I was able to trick the captcha into thinking I held it for *just* the right amount of time (in my experiments, the captcha hold-down time is randomized and 10 seconds ensures enough time to fully-complete the captcha).

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#px-captcha')
action = ActionChains(driver)
click = ActionChains(driver)
action.click_and_hold(element)
action.perform()
time.sleep(10)
action.release(element)
action.perform()
time.sleep(0.2)
action.release(element)
```

Comment: please edit `element = driver.find_element_by_selector('#px-captcha')` to `element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#px-captcha')`

Comment: Done!  I forgot my custom driver function was named different than the actual function call for the standard webdriver

Comment: I can not get it to work. Could you check how to fix the code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69547559/minimal-working-press-and-hold-example-in-selenium

Comment: @user1424739 Unfortunately, ever since Walmart pushed the new look/version of their website, I haven't been able to modify my implementation of this to get it working again

Comment: PX captcha has become really smart now, with Selenium, no matter if you click and hold manually or via code, it doesnt work, it just shows captcha again.

Comment: in 2023 this code of piece still working :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full code to handle the Press & Hold captcha case. I have add code to automatically resize the captcha box size to click & hold in the middle of the captcha that is required to be verified.

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time
from time import sleep
from random import randint

chromedriver = "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
chromedriver = "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

url = "{Your URL}"
driver.get(url)
sleep(randint(2,3))

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='px-captcha']")
# print(len(element.text), '- Value found by method text')
action = ActionChains(driver)
click = ActionChains(driver)
frame_x = element.location['x']
frame_y = element.location['y']
# print('x: ', frame_x)
# print('y: ', frame_y)
# print('size box: ', element.size)
# print('x max click: ', frame_x + element.size['width'])
# print('y max click: ', frame_y + element.size['height'])
x_move = frame_x + element.size['width']*0.5
y_move = frame_y + element.size['height']*0.5
action.move_to_element_with_offset(element, x_move, y_move).click_and_hold().perform()
time.sleep(10)
action.release(element)
action.perform()
time.sleep(0.2)
action.release(element)
```

Comment: I can not get it to work. Could you check how to fix the code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69547559/minimal-working-press-and-hold-example-in-selenium

Answer (score 2):

@Prata Palit
'Press & Hold' button uses 10 iframes,
Random one iframe is visible, other 9 ifame is hidden,
The iframe has cross-domain and cannot get element with javascript.
'Press and hold'  button complete the verification speed is also random.
I used feature matching with FLANN.

1. Get a verified captcha image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADzMT.png
   Use selenium screen shot to get captcha element image.
   Don't use OS screen shot.
   Because you need to compare the same screenshot.
2. Check whether the page contains captcha
   press and hold
   Loop the following operations at intervals of 0.5 seconds
   Use the pre-prepared captcha to compare with the captcha on the page
   until match or timeout

match captcha https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCqhy.jpg

```
def solve_blocked(self, retry=3):
    '''
    Solve blocked
    (Cross-domain iframe cannot get elements temporarily)
    Simulate the mouse press and hold to complete the verification
    '''
    if not retry:
        return False
    element = None
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(self.browser,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'px-captcha')))
        # Wait for the px-captcha element styles to fully load
        time.sleep(0.5)
    except BaseException as e:
        self.logger.info(f'px-captcha element not found')
        return
    self.logger.info(f'solve blocked:{self.browser.current_url}, Retry {retry} remaining times')
    template = cv2.imread(os.path.join(settings.TPL_DIR, 'captcha.png'), 0)
    # Set the minimum number of feature points to match value 10
    MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 8 
    if  element:
        self.logger.info(f'start press and hold')
        ActionChains(self.browser).click_and_hold(element).perform()
        start_time = time.time()
        while 1:
            # timeout
            if time.time() - start_time > 20:
                break
            x, y = element.location['x'], element.location['y']
            width, height = element.size.get('width'), element.size.get('height')                
            left = x*self.pixelRatio
            top = y*self.pixelRatio
            right = (x+width)*self.pixelRatio
            bottom = (y+height)*self.pixelRatio
            # full screenshot
            png = self.browser.get_screenshot_as_png() 
            im = Image.open(BytesIO(png))
            # px-captcha screenshot
            im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) 
            target = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(im),cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)  
            # Initiate SIFT detector
            sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
            # find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
            kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(template,None)
            kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(target,None)
            # create set FLANN match
            FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
            index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
            search_params = dict(checks = 50)
            flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
            matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
            # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
            good = []
            # Discard matches greater than 0.7
            for m,n in matches:
                if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
                    good.append(m)
            self.logger.info( "matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
            if len(good)>=MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
                self.logger.info(f'release button')
                ActionChains(self.browser).release(element).perform()
                return
            time.sleep(0.5)
    time.sleep(1)
    retry -= 1
    self.solve_blocked(retry)
```

Comment: Can you please share full snippet?

Comment: Not exactly sure what is "captcha.png" here?

Comment: @ilbets [captcha.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADzMT.png)

Comment: @lucasaisin what is `self.pixelRatio`?, it is not defined, please edit the code so that everyone can use this code directly without changing anything

Comment: @lucasaisin can you please edit the code? also please include imported libraries in the code.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use Chromedriver Undetected..
You can follow the below git link for setup.
Quite simple to integrate
https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.example.com')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

pixelRatio = 2
def solve_blocked(browser, retry=3):
    '''
    Solve blocked
    (Cross-domain iframe cannot get elements temporarily)
    Simulate the mouse press and hold to complete the verification
    '''
    if not retry:
        return False
    element = None
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(browser,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'px-captcha')))
        # Wait for the px-captcha element styles to fully load
        time.sleep(0.5)
    except BaseException as e:
        print(f'px-captcha element not found')
        return
    print(f'solve blocked:{browser.current_url}, Retry {retry} remaining times')
    template = cv2.imread(os.path.join('./captcha.png'), 0)
    # Set the minimum number of feature points to match value 10
    MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 8 
    if  element:
        print(f'start press and hold')
        ActionChains(browser).click_and_hold(element).perform()
        start_time = time.time()
        while 1:
            if time.time() - start_time > 20:
                break
            x, y = element.location['x'], element.location['y']
            width, height = element.size.get('width'), element.size.get('height')                
            left = x * pixelRatio
            top = y * pixelRatio
            right = (x+width) * pixelRatio
            bottom = (y+height) * pixelRatio
            png = browser.get_screenshot_as_png() 
            im = Image.open(BytesIO(png))
            im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) 
            target = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(im),cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)  
            # Initiate SIFT detector
            sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
            # find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
            kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(template,None)
            kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(target,None)
            # create set FLANN match
            FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
            index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
            search_params = dict(checks = 50)
            flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
            matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
            # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
            good = []
            # Discard matches greater than 0.7
            for m,n in matches:
                if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
                    good.append(m)
            print( "Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
            if len(good)>=MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
                print(f'release button')
                ActionChains(browser).release(element).perform()
                return
            time.sleep(0.5)
    time.sleep(1)
    retry -= 1
    solve_blocked(retry)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","127.0.0.1:9222")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='./chromedriver')
while browser.window_handles:
    browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])
    if browser.window_handles.__len__() == 1:
        break
    browser.close()
browser.get('about:blank')
browser.get('https://www.walmart.com/blocked')
# # You need to add the following method to the middleware
solve_blocked(browser)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @ Prakash Dahal  The following is a  full code snippet

Comment: @Usman Gani  The following is a  full code snippet

Comment: @ilbets The following is a  full code snippet