# Minimal working press and hold example in Selenium

Tags: selenium, captcha

[How to long press (Press and Hold) mouse left key using only Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68636955/how-to-long-press-press-and-hold-mouse-left-key-using-only-selenium-in-python)

I am trying the answer by zirene-nguyễn in the above page. But it does not click-and-hold the button. How can I fix it so that it works to bypass the captcha in this example?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.walmart.com/blocked?url=L2lwL0Nsb3JveC1EaXNpbmZlY3RpbmctV2lwZXMtMjI1LUNvdW50LVZhbHVlLVBhY2stQ3Jpc3AtTGVtb24tYW5kLUZyZXNoLVNjZW50LTMtUGFjay03NS1Db3VudC1FYWNoLzE0ODk4MzY1&uuid=9ed7f800-f288-11eb-ad50-1b3c9c7d7310&vid=9cf07351-f288-11eb-9ab5-ef26d206453b&g=b')

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='px-captcha']")
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

action = ActionChains(driver)
frame_x = element.location['x']
frame_y = element.location['y']
x_move = frame_x + element.size['width']*0.5
y_move = frame_y + element.size['height']*0.5
action.move_to_element_with_offset(element, x_move, y_move).click_and_hold().perform()
import time
time.sleep(10)
action.release(element)
action.perform()
time.sleep(0.2)
action.release(element)
```

Comment: Your code is missing an import statement as well as a click event. It doesn't look like you copied and pasted all the code. I'd re-review that and re-copy and re-paste it in.

Comment: I think you need a pause in your actionschain there... .click_and_hold().pause(seconds).release()...

Comment: @pcalkins Could you test what is the complete correct code should be?

Comment: @pcalkins I tried `action.move_to_element_with_offset(element, x_move, y_move).click_and_hold().pause(10).release()` and deleted everthing after `import time`, I don't see the button is pressed and hold.

Comment: make sure you are targeting the correct element.  Are you sure the <div> takes the click there?  I would also consider removing the offset.  Not sure why that's there, and your moving it by an odd amount... (taking the location + width /2... probably much too large an offset... remember that the offset is the amount you want to move off of center...  click should be clicking exactly in the middle... at least that's true for a normal click... not entirely sure about click in actionschain but I'd assume it's the same.)

Comment: @pcalkins Is there a way to visualize where the moveto target is?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that... you can just use 0,0 as offsets... or just use move_to_element(element).  It should already be in the center of the element.

Comment: @pcalkins It doesn't work. Could you test the whole program before put comments that don't work?

Comment: For my previous comment, what I meant was to see where the pointer is moved to when I issue a move_to_element* command.