# How to solve Walmart Robot or Human challenge?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, captcha

I have compiled a code that would *Create an Account* on https://www.walmart.com/ using selenium python. The code opens Walmart website goes to Create an account tab, fills the required details and click on Create Account button. However, the problem is Walmart's ***Human verification challenge*** which appears randomly at any stage. Following are the snapshots that shows the Human verification challenge appearing just after opening the URL or after clicking on create account button:

[image: Robot or Human?-after opening URL]

[image: Robot or Human?-after clicking on create account button]

I have found a code on stackoverflow to bypass this challenge (shown below) but it didn;t work fro me.

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#px-captcha')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.click_and_hold(element)
action.perform()
time.sleep(100)
action.release(element)
action.perform()
time.sleep(0.2)
action.release(element)
```

For reference my python code is as follows:

```
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = "https://www.walmart.com/"

first_name = "chuza"
last_name = "789"
email_id = "chuza789@gmail.com"
password = "Eureka1@"

options = Options()

s=Service('C:/Users/Samiullah/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/win32/96.0.4664.45/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    "source":
        "const newProto = navigator.__proto__;"
        "delete newProto.webdriver;"
        "navigator.__proto__ = newProto;"
})
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get(url)

sign_in_btn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Sign In']")))
actions.move_to_element(sign_in_btn).perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[normalize-space()="Create an account"]'))).click()

f_name = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'first-name-su')
l_name = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'last-name-su')
email = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email-su')  
pswd = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password-su')
f_name.send_keys(first_name)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
l_name.send_keys(last_name)
driver.implicitly_wait(2.5)
email.send_keys(email_id)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
pswd.send_keys(password)
driver.implicitly_wait(2.8)
###
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-automation-id='signup-submit-btn']"))).click()
```

Can anyone please guide me how to solve Walmart's Robot or Human? Challenge and how to integrate it with my existing code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to scrape Walmart and having a similar issue.

Comment: @salman dinani I have a solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71290542/18328786

Comment: @salman dinani I have a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71290542/18328786

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to overcome this is to check for this element presence.
In case this element appears - perform the page reloading until this element is no more present.
Something like this:

```
human_dialog = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-labelledby='ld_modalTitle_0']")
while human_dialog:
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(1)
    human_dialog = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-labelledby='ld_modalTitle_0']")
```