# How does Selenium click and hold in Golang?

Tags: selenium, go, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

The Python library has supported the click_and_hold function: [1]: [How to long press (Press and Hold) mouse left key using only Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68636955/how-to-long-press-press-and-hold-mouse-left-key-using-only-selenium-in-python/68848948)

How does Selenium click and hold with Selenium by Golang?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two div containing ids: draggable and droppable and you want to drag & drop draggable into droppable.
You use chromedriver and it's instantiated as driver. 
This case is an example and you could wait between ButtonDown and ButtonUp.

```golang
drag, err := driver.FindElement(selenium.ByID, "draggable")  
if err != nil {  
    return err  
}  
drop, err := driver.FindElement(selenium.ByID, "droppable")  
if err != nil {  
    return err  
}  
drag.Click()  
driver.ButtonDown()  
err = drag.MoveTo(100, 50)  
if err != nil {  
    return err  
}  
driver.ButtonUp()
```